# Send list parameter using swagger

Tags: c#, swagger

I have class with Guid as:

```
public class GuidIdTableType
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I use in my model as a list of guids like:

```
public class InsertOrUpdateModel
    {
      ....
     public IList<GuidIdTableType> MyTableType { get; set; } = new List<GuidIdTableType>();
    }
```

Then I execute swagger and try to send json as:

```
"MyTableType":["0C789CE8-D680-EA11-8456-00155DB55502", "0D789CE8-D680-EA11-8456-00155DB55502"]
```

But this throw an exception:

> [   "Error converting value
>   \"[\"0C789CE8-D680-EA11-8456-00155DB55502\",
>   \"0D789CE8-D680-EA11-8456-00155DB55502\"]\" to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Dto.Models.Helpers.GuidIdTableType]'.
>   Path 'MyTableType', line 14, position 101." ]

What is the correct way to send a list using swagger? Regards

Comment: "I have a list of Guid" - but post shows something very different in the code - can you clarify if you want `List<Guid>` or list of custom classes?

Comment: I want to send a `List<Guid>` @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: That's sort of unfortunate as clearly server side code does not expect list of Guids but instead list of `GuidIdTableType`... You have to either change what you want to send or what code expects to receive... There is no way to convince server side code to accept format it does not expect.